# I have used all my spare neurons trying to figure out why this CSS is not working on this test site of mine

Tags: html, css

```css
#faleConnosco a {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

#faleConnosco a:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="faleConnosco"><a href="https://example.com">FALE CONNOSCO</a></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

this works perfectly. You mouse over the words and a red oval appears and the text turns white

but when I add this code to [this site I am testing](http://katkay.com/teste), it doesn't.

Hover on `FALA CONNOSCO`... it will not turn red.

I have used all my spare neurons trying to figure out why. Not even the cursor changes to a pointer.

Comment: It's being covered by a margin. Try adding this CSS and then roll over the button.
.twentyseventeen-panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

Comment: I saw it not working on your site (as you said), and then I brought up Chrome tools and kept selecting the 3 or so elements that were covering it.  Then I chose "hide element" on each.  Eventually, the button was getting mouse events and I could see that button turn red.

Comment: how do you see that?

Comment: Please include a [mre] here on Stack Overflow of the problem code. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a div, "twentyseventeen-panel", with a negative margin covering the button. This CSS should fix it.

```
#post-98.twentyseventeen-panel {
margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

This was discovered by using the dev tool in the Chrome browser. You can use it by hovering over the item in question and righ-click to select "inspect". This will then open the developer tool and have an HTML element highlighted and opened. This is where you can drill down by opening each HTML element within the first one until you find the button. Upon selecting each element you will be able to see CSS properties. The one that stuck out most was the negative margin of `-100px` on `.twentyseventeen-panel`  because typically that can cause issues. Trial and error helps by toggling the CSS property checkboxes to see how each effects the HTML. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I will accept the answer in 3 minutes but please explain on the question how you have discovered that? What steps and tools you have used?

Comment: @DuckDucking you should be able to right-click on the element and click 'inspect' from the menu that comes up. The console comes up on the browser then and you can see what styles are being applied to the element. There are a number of debugging extensions that you can add (depending on your preferred browser). I use firebug in Chrome. By-the-by, while the Fala Connosco doesn't turn red, the link below it does (on hover) .. it seemed to me like you were targeting the incorrect element? But whatever works for you..

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, brilliant! Thanks